# Plesk, Email with localy established domain where the mail server is external

Tags: email, postfix-mta, plesk

I have a big problem with setting up a domain. The web services are established on our server, but the email functions are on another company's server. When we try to send an email through our server, it tries to send it locally instead of sending it to the other server, resulting in a 'no account here' error.

Thank you for helping me out. Best regards.

Edit: OS Debian 6, IMAP: Courier, Send: Postfix, CP: Plesk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to this, we are using Plesk 11.5.3 on a setup where a single mail service is activated for all domains.

So each domain cannot have the mail service turned on or off individually.

We had the same problem as Franco, and we fixed this by running the following command for each domain that had external email:

```
# /usr/local/psa/bin/mail --off domain.com
```

Works perfectly, and removes any previously created local email addresses from Postfix.

Answer (score 0):

"The problem is because the server will attempt to deliver emails for the domain name locally by default. To resolve that problem you would need to set it to use the domain name's MX record."

The simple answer is to disable mail services for the subscription.

Untick the box for "Activate mail service on domain".